# DynamoDBContext with conditional update

Tags: conditional-statements, updates, amazon-dynamodb

in my application i'm using amazon object persistence model and use DynamoDBContext for operations(CURD and execute queries). i need to know that how can i use conditional update using DynamoDBContext. and it should be asynchronous.

I know the way of doing it using amazon low-level API.

my application is developed using C# Dot Net(4.5)
thank you.

Answer (score 3):

.NET Async DynamoDBContext.Save call [uses SaveHelper](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-net/blob/84afada7f15263600155fe314cad09f2802338bc/sdk/src/Services/DynamoDBv2/Custom/DataModel/_async/Context.Async.cs#L58).
SaveHelper [calls UpdateHelper with an operationConfig](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-net/blob/84afada7f15263600155fe314cad09f2802338bc/sdk/src/Services/DynamoDBv2/Custom/DataModel/Context.cs#L243).
As DynamoDBOperationConfig [has a ConditionalOperator field](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-net/blob/84afada7f15263600155fe314cad09f2802338bc/sdk/src/Services/DynamoDBv2/Custom/DataModel/Configs.cs#L132), you may try using that to condition puts/updates on attribute values. Note that you can only enforce conditions on one item in this call. If you do that, you will not be able to overwrite an item that already exists, thereby enforcing uniqueness. I suggest you use a UUID instead of an incrementing number for your hash key though. While [atomic counters](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/WorkingWithItems.html#WorkingWithItems.AtomicCounters) are supported in the context of one item, they are not supported across all the items of a table. For conditional writes not supported by the DynamoDBContext.Save call, you can always use [the low-level API](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-net/blob/84afada7f15263600155fe314cad09f2802338bc/sdk/src/Services/DynamoDBv2/Generated/Model/UpdateItemRequest.cs#L49) with a [condition expression](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Expressions.SpecifyingConditions.html#Expressions.SpecifyingConditions.ConditionExpressions) to perform your conditional write.

Comment: thank you Alexander Patrikalakis. actuality i need to create auto increment number (to hold unique ID) as we can do in relational database. my plan is to do it using conditional update. i know that it is possible to do it using atomic number in dyanmodb. but my application must support concurrent request.

Comment: thank you. ConditionalOperator field has only "AND" "OR". and required ID should be readable. can not use UUID.

Comment: thank you Alexander. i used to following approach. http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/VersionSupportHLAPI.html

Comment: You can't do anything meaningful with the CondtionalOperator since there is no way to specify conditions to go with it.  Your reference to PutItemOperationConfig is misleading.