# unable to handle Amazon.DynamoDBv2.Model.ConditionalCheckFailedException

Tags: c#, asynchronous, exception, amazon-dynamodb

when i execute the following code Amazon.DynamoDBv2.Model.ConditionalCheckFailedException is not catching.

## Button click

```
public DelegateCommand SaveCommand
{
  get
  {
    _SaveCommand = new DelegateCommand(async (arg) => { await 
    this.SaveCommandExecuted(arg); }, this.SaveCommandCanExecute);
    return _SaveCommand;
  }

  set
  {
   _SaveCommand = value;
   OnPropertyChanged("SaveCommand");
   }
 }
```

## Save method content

```
        public async Task SaveCommandExecuted(object parameter)        
        {     
         try            
         {                                                 
          await PatientDataSource.Instance.SavePatient(Patient);             
         }
         catch (Amazon.DynamoDBv2.Model.ConditionalCheckFailedException ex)
         {                
          Exception = ex.Message;
         }            
    }
```

## Database operation method

```
public async Task SavePatient(Patient patient)   
{
 var context = CommonUtils.Instance.DynamoDBContext;             
 try
 {
   patient.PatientId = 1;
   await context.SaveAsync<Patient>(patient);
 }
 catch(Amazon.DynamoDBv2.Model.ConditionalCheckFailedException ex)
 {
   throw ex;
 }            
}
```

can anyone please advice.

Answer (score 0):

DynamoDBContext (the equivalent of DynamoDBMapper in the .NET SDK) conditions on the version attribute of the ORM object, in your your case, that is the Patient class, and on anything else in DynamoDBOperationConfig. The fact that you are unable to catch ConditionalCheckFailedException suggests that you do not have concurrent writes happening on the same patient. Please see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31066280/dynamodbcontext-with-conditional-update) as well for details.

Comment: thank you Alexander, im getting run time exception. it says, "ConditionalCheckFailedException was unhandled by user code".

Comment: in SavePatient, you throw the ConditionalCheckFailedException, and you catch it in SaveCommandExecuted and assign its message to Exception. In the code you provided I do not see where the ConditionalCheckFailedException could be thrown from. Please provide a stack trace of the exception that was not caught to help further debugging.

Comment: thank you for the comment. problem is that exception is bubbled in the visual studio only and can be continue it. it is possible to run the application exe which is created under debug folder without any issue.

Comment: try: Debug.Writeline(ex.ToString()) right before "throw ex;" in SavePatient?